# Performance implicit -vs- explicit conversion in a SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a performance hit in SQL when a stored procedure implicitly converts a varchar(max)to a numeric? I understand that converting a non-numeric string would be a bad issue but I am more curious about the performance with ideal data.

Comment: With ideal data, the data would be a numeric data type, not a string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think performance should be your concern here: accuracy is the key.

If you allow an implicit conversion you cannot guarantee the scale and precision of the data type chosen by the optimizer.

If you explicitly declare the type then you are able to obtain a deterministic result.

If you *really* want to pick on performance then I imagine the explicit will be faster as the implicit will have to scan a sample of rows first in order to **assume** what type it should cast to.

**Update:** Imagine you have an implicit conversion on a value used in a comparison: if the implicit conversion data type does not match that of the comparative column you will incur a further performance problem.

Comment: I understand about the data accuracy and agree 100%. I always push using strongly typed data. I am just trying to learn a little bit about what other issues implicit might cause. Thanks

Comment: From real world experience, I concur that implicit data conversions when the types do not match, say varchar vs nvarchar, can cause bad performance problems, especially as the # records in the table(s) gets large.